# Error Starting Office SharePoint Server Search Service

Tags: 2007, search

I keep receiving the following error when attempting to start the Office SharePoint Server Search Service.  Looking for solutions.  Thanks

---

### Services

Could not start the Office SharePoint Server Search service on Local Computer.

Error 1392: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a problem external to SharePoint itself. Try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176646